# How do you subset data based on a separate quality of the data

Tags: r, bar-chart, subset

I have a set of length data where each point is associated with a specific year:

```
structure(list(Year = 1982:2016, Length = c(0.345, 0.712, 1.553, 
0.494, 0.562, 0.816, 0.438, 0.311, 0.544, 0.409, 0.413, 0.424, 
0.338, 0.339, 0.211, 0.315, 0.234, 0.169, 0.32, 0.16, 0.403, 
0.339, 0.078, 0.149, 0.093, 0.231, 0.174, 0.266, 0.261, 0.068, 
0.097, 0.063, 0.089, 0.059, 0.064)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-35L))

df
   Year Length
1  1982  0.345
2  1983  0.712
3  1984  1.553
4  1985  0.494
5  1986  0.562
6  1987  0.816
7  1988  0.438
8  1989  0.311
9  1990  0.544
10 1991  0.409
11 1992  0.413
12 1993  0.424
13 1994  0.338
14 1995  0.339
15 1996  0.211
16 1997  0.315
17 1998  0.234
18 1999  0.169
19 2000  0.320
20 2001  0.160
21 2002  0.403
22 2003  0.339
23 2004  0.078
24 2005  0.149
25 2006  0.093
26 2007  0.231
27 2008  0.174
28 2009  0.266
29 2010  0.261
30 2011  0.068
31 2012  0.097
32 2013  0.063
33 2014  0.089
34 2015  0.059
35 2016  0.064
```

I want to be able to filter the data to only show certain years; the years I need to look at will change, so I want it to be easy to display different years. The end goal is to show the data in a bar plot where each point is labeled with the year associated with it.

I am fairly inexperienced with R, so I am not even sure if I should store the data as a data frame, a matrix, or a vector. Googling hasn't really been helpful because there are so many different ways to subset data. Can anyone help me out with this?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @gabe_mh! Thank you for your question. 

Subseting a data.frame on a certain condition is a fairly standard question. So I will recomand to remove this quesiton. 

However, I highly recomand for you to learn more about how to work with different data structure in R. Don't feel discourage, it is a learning curve and you are on the right path! 

Here is a useful link if you are interested: 

1. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/03/learning-about-data-structures-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `dplyr` and `ggplot2` package:

say we want to remove all year before 2000 -> `filter(!(Year %in% c(1982:1999)))`

and then we plot with `geom_col()`

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  filter(!(Year %in% c(1982:1999))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Length))+
  geom_col()
```

[image]